# PHP ignores newline when using echo to display a text stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, echo, newline

Im working on a ticketing system and there's a part where the user inputs his/her comments in a text area. The whole text (including the new line), no matter how long oe how many ENTERs you press, is stored in mysql, I checked when I viewed the records using phpMyAdmin. But unfortunately "echo"-ing it in PHP ignores the newline. say, if i input this block of text,

HI

HELLO

HOW

ARE YOU

when echoed, it goes like this:

HI HELLO HOW ARE YOU

it ignores newline and converts it to space instead. how do I fix that?

Comment: Where is it displayed? Command line? In a browser?

Comment: you need php function nl2br() for display.

Answer (score 5):

It's because browser ignores new lines (it's `<br/>` tag for new line in browser, not `\r\n`). To get new lines converted to break tags, use `nl2br($stringFromDb);`

Answer (score 5):

It's not `PHP`, in `HTML`: a new line is a tag, not a character, you might wanna try this:

```
echo('HI<br>');
echo('Hello<br>');
...
```

or if you have these words in 1 string you can convert new line characters to `br` tags:

```
$str = "HI
HELLO";
echo nl2br($str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to add a new line tag between each echo.

```
echo "Hello"."<br>";
echo "How";
...
```

Thats just the most simple and dirty way of doing it.

Comment: That is not what the OP was asking. He obviously can't use the br tag as you suggest, simply because his entire string comes from a database, and he wants the line breaks to replace the \n (wherever that may be in the text)